# LookAt matrix distorts when looking up or down

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I am using a lookAt matrix calculated in an open source math library I found for LWJGL called [JOML](https://github.com/JOML-CI/Java-OpenGL-Math-Library) for free cam in my game. It works well when rotating left and right, but looking up and down seems to cause major distortions issues similar to heavily increasing the FOV.

Looking straight forward:
[image: Regular]

But when looking up:
[image: Looking up]

And when looking down:
[image: Looking down]

I haven't been able to find someone with a similar error, and no one using JOML has reported this. I'm not the best at matrix math, so all my tries at calculating my own lookAt matrix were fails.
If someone could make a lookAt matrix using JOML, or say any one of my (most likely) possible errors, that would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the lookAt code provided by that library is just this (I'm leaving the actual source code out and only keep the comments, as they nicely explain the steps which are done):

```
public final static void lookAt(Vector3f position, Vector3f centre, Vector3f up, Matrix4f dest) {
        // Compute direction from position to lookAt
        // Normalize direction
        // Normalize up
        // right = direction x up
        // up = right x direction
        // Set matrix elements
    }
```

And this code is just *wrong*. Interestingly, I've seen this mistake before. It is actually the same error that that the ["official" `gluLookAt()` manpage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) still contains (the actual glu implementations do not have the error, just that documentation is wrong).

What this code does is building an orthonormal basis. And the problem is that the up vector is normalized *before* the cross product for calculating `right`. The assumption seems to be that when building the cross product of two unit length vectors, the result will also be a unit lenght vector. But that is a common misconception. What's actually holding true is just:

```
length( cross( a, b) ) == lenght(a) * length(b) * sin(alpha)
```

where alpha is the angle between `a` and `b`. So the unit lenght assumption only holds *if the vectors are already orthogonal*. As the vectors are never re-normalized after the cross product, the resulting basis is not orthonormal, but will introduce some non-uniform scaling. The `lookAt` assumes that the inverse rotation can be calculated by the transposed matrix, which will completely fail in this case.

The distortion you see will get more severe when the angle between the viewing direction and your up vector will move away from 90 degrees.

The correct way to deal with this is just doing the normalization at a different point. Don't normalize the up-vector before the cross-product, but normalize it's result instead. Then, you have two unit-lenght vectors orthogonal to each other, and the second cross-product will also work as expected. So the actual lookAt function should be:

```
        // Compute direction from position to lookAt
        // Normalize direction
        // right = direction x up
        // Normalize right
        // up = right x direction
        // Set matrix elements
```

Comment: An alternative is to make the up vector orthogonal to the direction vector by using the dot product between them. Something like `up -= dot(up, dir) * dir`. Then normalize the up vector, and the cross product of up and direction will give the correct right vector without any additional normalization. Probably more efficient in cases where that matters.

Comment: Yup, it worked! Up vector was already normalized when putting it as a parameter, but I commented that out just in case and normalized the right. Thank you for your time!