# C++ 3D Scene distorts when looking up or down

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d

I have a problem that is identical to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409318/lookat-matrix-distorts-when-looking-up-or-down), however the solution provided doesn't solve my issue.

I'm developing this using the PixelGameEngine from javidx9, so I have implemented all these functions myself.

This is the code for the LookAt function:

```
static Matrix4 LookAtMatrix(const Vector3& pos, const Vector3& target) {
        if(pos == target) { return LookAtMatrix(pos, target + Vector3(.01f, 0, 0)); }

        //get new forward direction
        Vector3 newFor = (target - pos).normalized();

        //get right direction
        Vector3 newRight; 
        if(newFor == Vector3::UP || newFor == Vector3::DOWN) { 
            newRight = Vector3::RIGHT; 
        } else {
            newRight = (Vector3::UP.cross(newFor)).normalized(); 
        }

        //get up direction
        Vector3 newUp = newRight.cross(newFor); 

        //make look-at matrix
        return Matrix4(
            newRight.x, newRight.y, newRight.z, 0,
            newUp.x,    newUp.y,    newUp.z,    0,
            newFor.x,   newFor.y,   newFor.z,   0,
            pos.x,      pos.y,      pos.z,      1
        );
    }
```

You may notice that some of my cross products are flipped when compared to other implementations, but it works with moving the camera around just fine.

Here is a gif of the warping:

[image: gif of warping]

I don't understand what's going wrong, and my friend who I'm working on this with went at it for weeks and couldn't find a solution. I don't know what else could be causing the problem.

A quick run down of our rendering process, in case that's the issue is

```
//project points to camera space
//clip triangles against view plane
//project triangles to screenspace
//clip triangles against camera's view fulcrum
//draw triangles
```

If more detail is needed anywhere I'll be happy to provide it. Thanks.

Comment: In look-at, only translation and rotation may come out. This is something, you could simply check in your matrix (for debugging). So, row vectors 0, 1, and 2 must be upright to each other. If not, you get shearing which might explain the distortion. (Additionally, they must have length 1. If not you get scaling.) Though, I'm not 100 % sure what (distortion) I see in your GIF animation. Perspective projection (with an unlucky configuration) can cause such or similar effects as well. I would trust the numbers only... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff when you say that row vectors 0, 1, and 2 must be upright to each other, you mean they must be orthogonal, right? My friend has looked over the perspective projection a bunch as well, but I have yet to. I will check that the lookAt matrix isn't trying to scale somehow as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was so small it went over looked for weeks. All we had to do was flip the y axis on the newUp vector, since our y axis is flipped, or something. I'm not sure.

Comment: Flipping one axis results in a left-handed coordinate system (when it was a right-handed before). I'm a bit surprised that this was your actual issue. However, fine that you could fix it. With a bit experience, it's not that difficult to "read" matrices. Before I got this experience I was surprised and impressed when my professor looked once over my shoulder and told me "Oh, a rotation matrix..." after a short glance. On the other hand, he was a Doctor in math... :-)